# Adding custom images to a Calendar view

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I am trying to add custom images into Drupal's calendar view by checking 'nid' of a node (or taxonomy term in future). I am writing this custom code in views-view-field--calendar--nid.tpl.

The problem is that, what ever is output by views-view-field--calendar--nid.tpl is also inserted into 'id' attribute of **div** tag. Please see the second **div** tag.

254 was the output and it is also inserted into 'id' attribute.

```
<div class="view-item view-item-calendar"> 
  <div class="calendar monthview" id="calendar:
 254:changed:0:0"> 
              <div id="nid" class="view-field view-data-nid"> 


 254      </div>  
      </div>
```

So when views-view-field--calendar--nid.tpl outputs **img** tag, it also get inserted into 'id' attribute, which breaks the second **div** tag.

Please, see following output

```
<div class="view-item view-item-calendar"> 
  <div class="calendar monthview" id="calendar:
 <img src="http://www.programmingnature.com/stackoverflow_32.png"> </img>255:changed:0:1">
              <div id="nid" class="view-field view-data-nid"> 


 <img src="http://www.programmingnature.com/stackoverflow_32.png"> </img>255      </div>  
      </div>    
</div>
```

**Screenshot:**

[alt text http://img201.imageshack.us/img201/3140/calendarproblem.png](http://img201.imageshack.us/img201/3140/calendarproblem.png)

Please note that Calender view tried to insert the output with **img** tag inside that 'id' attribute and everything now is messed up...

How can I prevent Calender from inserting output into 'id' attribute? Or is there any alternative way to insert images in Calender view ?

Following is the code of views-view-field--calendar--nid.tpl

```
<?php

$results = $variables['view']->result;
$nid=$output;

$newOutput="";

foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
//Find the matching nid

 if ($nid==255) {

 $newOutput.= '<img src="http://www.programmingnature.com/stackoverflow_32.png"> </img>';
 }

 $newOutput.=$nid;


    }

 print  $newOutput; 

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calendar's pretty silly. What's occurring is that the calendar view is creating an ID based on all available fields in the view and stringing them together to create a unique ID. Great in theory, but it assumes a lot (like you not doing what you're trying to do here).

You can see what it's attempting to do in `template_preprocess_calendar_node()` in theme/theme.inc. The solution is to create your own preprocess function, `mytheme_preprocess_calendar_node(&$vars)`, and set `$vars['fields']['id']` to something more sane, like perhaps `'calendar-' . $vars['node']->nid`.

Comment: A module can also implement `hook_preprocess_calendar_node()`. Using a custom module implementing such function is better, as you can use any themes you want without to add `template_preprocess_calendar_node()` to each of them.

Comment: I will definitely try writing my own preprocess function. Can I add this function in the same template file?
@kiamlaluno, thanks for tip, writing a custom module looks better option

Comment: @Ajinkya Kulkarni, you can add it right to template.php in your theme. Just remember to flush your theme cache.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, since I just wanted to display a single image for a node, I changed

```
$newOutput.= '<img src="http://www.programmingnature.com/stackoverflow_32.png"> </img>';
```

to

```
$newOutput.= "<img src=http://www.programmingnature.com/stackoverflow_32.png> </img>";
```

Note, I just removed quotes from the string.

So, following output is generated by Calendar,

```
<div class="calendar monthview" id="calendar:<img src=http://www.programmingnature.com/stackoverflow_32.png> </img>255:changed:0:1"> 

    <div id="nid" class="view-field view-data-nid"> 

    <img src=http://www.programmingnature.com/stackoverflow_32.png> </img>255  

   </div>  
</div>
```

Well, **img** tag is still inserted into **ID** attribute, but **div** tag is not broken, and I get the correct output.

[alt text http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/4607/calendarproblemsolved.png](http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/4607/calendarproblemsolved.png)

Better permanent solution is to use preprocess function as suggested by **Mark** and  **kiamlaluno**